# How can I use scanlines on my LED monitor to gain performance over half of the pixels?

Tags: performance, graphics-card, display, resolution

In the old days, we had resolution features like scanlines and the amount of work the graphics adapter does would be reduced. I have FPS problems with some games so is there a way to use a video mode with scan lines? like, removing every other second horizontal line from the screen. and using a video mode like 1920, 540 instead of 1920x1080 and having a similar output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the game doesn't include a resolution that includes scanline options, then it probably isn't possible.  The only other option may be to just go with a smaller resolution.  And especially in games with high motion, the decrease in resolution will probably not even be noticeable.

For years, that has been the dilemma.  Do you try to optimize the game for high resolution, or optimize the resolution for high performance?  And each gamer had to figure out how much resolution they were willing to sacrifice for performance, or how much performance they were willing to sacrifice to get a better resolution, depending on which priority you started with as the primary requirement.

I often started with the low resolutions and worked my way up until I hit a point where the performance took too much a hit, and dropped one step back the other direction.